# JQuery Slideshow - Two elements side by side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have created a simple automatic image slider for my website in HTML, CSS and jQuery. It works great for images. However, what I now want to do is put two elements inside each slide, for example, a picture and its accompanying text. I have attached my current slider below.
HTML

```
    <div id="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide"><img src="slides/1.png" style="width: 1000; height: 360;"/></li>
            <li class="slide"><img src="slides/2.png" style="width: 1000; height: 360;"/></li>
            <li class="slide"><img src="slides/3.png" style="width: 1000; height: 360;"/></li>
            <li class="slide"><img src="slides/1.png" style="width: 1000; height: 360;"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#slider {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width: 4000px;
    height: 360px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slider .slide {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 360px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    var width = 1000;
    var animationSpeed = 1000;
    var pause = 5000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
    var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

    var interval;

    setInterval(function() {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
            if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
});
```

What I would like is to have images 360x640px and a div/span for text next to each image which is 360x360px, giving each slide a total width of 1000px. I have tried a number of ideas but I can't seem to make it work. I am hoping that someone with much more experience can help. Thanks :)

Comment: add `px` in `"width: 1000;` and also in height

Comment: @ketan Thanks, yes that was an error of mine. However even after I fix that I can't make it work. What I want is <li class="slide"><img src="slides/1.png" style="width: 640px; height: 360px;"/><span>Text description</span></li>

Comment: or <li class="slide"><img src="slides/1.png" style="width: 640px; height: 360px;"/></li>
<li class="slide"><span>Text description</span></li>

Comment: @ketan Nevermind, floating the span right seems to have fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here it is what you need. https://jsfiddle.net/6rx6go3h/1/